# Amazon SES Template URLs {{values}} not Replaced by Values in Sent Emails

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

We want to use Amazon SES PHP to schedule newsletters to our mailing list, what I stumbled upon today is that in the URLs inside our templates the replacements are not performed so for example a registration button is passed to Amazon in the template as `"'<a href="https://example.com/register.php?id={{userid}}">Register</a>';` , In the emails the template has the link `https://example.com/register.php?id={{userid}}` , even thought the parameter is sent through ['ReplacementTemplateData'] for each email, also all parameters in the text areas seem to work perfectly fine and replace fine but all URL parameters behave the same way (they are not replaced) also the emails send fine if they are missing( this makes me think they are ignored or there is something we don't get as if a parameter from the Text Area that replaces correctly is missing the emails are not sent).

Answer (score 1):

Well i eventually figured out PHP was changing the html characters to url safe ones in the urls , thus i had to pass the html email template to amazon through rawurldecode .